# Multi-Label Classification R

Tags: r

I am trying to learn R. I have the following dataset, 28 variables, and 5 of them are labels (`Class, crown, root, trunk, collar`). First of all, I tried to use `RandomForest` to predict based on the class if a tree is sick or not.

Next, 
I need to predict which part of the tree is sick (crown, root, collar, trunk)

I need to use multi-label classification (`randomForestSRC`) or other packages.

If someone could provide an example how to use multi-label classification (or transform the label classes into binary form) , I would really appreciate.

Thank you in advance!

```
dput(ML)
structure(list(Sector = c(5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L), Plantation.year = c(2014L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2009L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2009L, 
2004L, 2006L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2009L, 2004L, 2005L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2014L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L), Diagnosis.year = c(2014L, 
2013L, NA, 2014L, 2013L, 2015L, 2013L, 2014L, 2013L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2014L, 2013L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2013L, 2015L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2015L, 2014L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 2015L, 2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2013L, 2015L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L), Next.diagnosis.year = c(2019L, 
NA, 2014L, 2014L, NA, 2018L, 2020L, 2014L, NA, 2017L, NA, 2014L, 
2016L, 2018L, 2020L, NA, NA, 2016L, NA, 2018L, 2018L, 2014L, 
2016L, 2014L, 2014L, NA, 2015L, NA, 2014L, NA, NA, 2014L, NA, 
NA, 2018L, 2017L, 2014L, NA, 2014L, 2020L, 2017L, 2017L, 2016L, 
NA, 2018L, 2020L, 2019L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2017L, 2018L), Stump.diameter = structure(c(2L, 
6L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
10L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 
8L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 11L), .Label = c("0 Ã  10 cm", "10 Ã  20 cm", 
"100 Ã  110 cm", "110 Ã  120 cm", "20 Ã  30 cm", "30 Ã  40 cm", 
"40 Ã  50 cm", "50 Ã  60 cm", "60 Ã  70 cm", "70 Ã  80 cm", "80 Ã  90 cm"
), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(4L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
9L, 5L, 8L, 1L, NA, NA, 13L, 7L, 15L, NA, 12L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 
8L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 11L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 
2L, 8L, 9L, 8L, NA, 12L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 
11L, 13L, 1L), .Label = c("acerifolia", "betulus", "campestris", 
"cordata", "excelsior", "grandiflora", "japonica", "nigra", "Other ", 
"platanoides", "pseudoplatanus", "styraciflua", "tomentosa", 
"tulipifera", "verrucosa"), class = "factor"), Traffic.frequence = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("passages frÃ©quents et arrÃªts frÃ©quents", 
"passages frÃ©quents ou arrÃªts", "quelques passages"), class = "factor"), 
    Botanical.category = structure(c(2L, 16L, 11L, 19L, 8L, 14L, 
    8L, 17L, 16L, 1L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 19L, 13L, 
    16L, 17L, 3L, 15L, 20L, 1L, 7L, 16L, 15L, 20L, 10L, 15L, 
    16L, 13L, 19L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 5L, 15L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 13L, 19L, 
    9L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 18L, 16L, 1L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("Acer", 
    "Alnus", "Betula", "Carpinus", "Celtis", "Cercis", "Cupressus", 
    "Fraxinus", "Liquidambar", "Liriodendron", "Magnolia", "Malus", 
    "Other ", "Picea", "Pinus", "Platanus", "Populus", "Robinia", 
    "Sophora", "Tilia"), class = "factor"), PLU.ident.number = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), PLU.ProtectionCateg = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Diagnosis.remarks = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Arbre Ã  abattre dans les 10 ans", 
    "Arbre Ã  abattre dans les 5 ans", "Arbre d'avenir incertain", 
    "Arbre d'avenir normal"), class = "factor"), Diagnosis.renewal.priority = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("de 1 Ã  5 ans", 
    "de 11 Ã  20 ans", "plus de 20 ans"), class = "factor"), 
    Reasoning.planting = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), .Label = "Remplacement", class = "factor"), Subcategory = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ESP151", "ESP174"
    ), class = "factor"), Development.stage = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Arbre d'espaces ouverts", 
    "Arbre de voirie"), class = "factor"), STADEDEDEVELOPPEMENT = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Arbre adulte", "Arbre jeune", 
    "Arbre vieillissant"), class = "factor"), Development.stage.diagnosis = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Arbre adulte", "Arbre jeune", 
    "Arbre vieillissant"), class = "factor"), Caterpillar.treat.priority = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Haute", "Moyenne"
    ), class = "factor"), Recommended.treatment = structure(c(2L, 
    NA, 2L, 8L, NA, 3L, 6L, 6L, NA, 6L, NA, 9L, 5L, 7L, 7L, NA, 
    NA, 1L, NA, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 6L, NA, 6L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 
    7L, NA, NA, 7L, 6L, 7L, NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, 7L, 2L, 
    6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("Abattage", "Controle", 
    "Controle rÃ©sistographe", "Controle tuteur, attache ou protection", 
    "Taille d'Ã©claircie", "Taille de bois mort", "Taille formation et mise au gabarit", 
    "Taille mise en sÃ©curitÃ©", "Taille rideau"), class = "factor"), 
    Sidewalk = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("non", 
    "oui"), class = "factor"), PLU.spatial.arrangement = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Variety = structure(c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Austriaca", "Glauca", 
    "Italica", "Pyramidalis"), class = "factor"), Vigor = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("vieillissement dÃ©pÃ©rissement", 
    "vigoureux", "vigueur intermÃ©diaire"), class = "factor"), 
    Class = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Collar = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Crown = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L), Root = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Trunk = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Sector", 
"Plantation.year", "Diagnosis.year", "Next.diagnosis.year", "Stump.diameter", 
"Species", "Traffic.frequence", "Botanical.category", "PLU.ident.number", 
"PLU.ProtectionCateg", "Diagnosis.remarks", "Diagnosis.renewal.priority", 
"Reasoning.planting", "Subcategory", "Development.stage", "STADEDEDEVELOPPEMENT", 
"Development.stage.diagnosis", "Caterpillar.treat.priority", 
"Recommended.treatment", "Sidewalk", "PLU.spatial.arrangement", 
"Variety", "Vigor", "Class", "Collar", "Crown", "Root", "Trunk"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -53L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question above, it seems the problem you are having are variables that have labels and are not numerical in some way? The easiest way to deal with this is to add another variable in your matrix for all 5 variables that are labels and have them have corresponding numbers. So Acer = 1, Alnus = 2 and so forth (class becomes class.id)

Now, with the randomforest package, categorical predictor variables must be specified as factors or else they will be wrongly treated as continuous. So to convert these, just add the code:

## converts to factor

`as.factor(class.id)`

## checks to see

`is.factor(class.id)`

Then you can use your random forest code from the randomforest package. I can't really figure out from your matrix of variables you have listed above, which variables determine whether a tree/species is sick or not, but in essence:

## predicts sickness based on your variables

```
sickness<-randomforest(class.id~variable1, variable2, etc., data=matrix, ntree=4000, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE
```

## this code allows you to see importance values as well as plot them

```
print(sickness)
importance(sickness)
varImpPlot(sickness)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem that I am trying to solve has 2 questions: 1. If a tree sick or not using only class label (I did it using Random Forest) 2. I need to tell which part of a tree is sick (crown, root, trunk, collar). I am trying to use MLPUGS package, but it is not suitable since I have non-numeric features.